# What would my actual duties be per this job description?

Tags: project-management, job-description

I am currently in university and a recruiter from a certain bank contacted me about an internship position and he sent me the job description but this stood out and I have done quite a lot of research but I am trying to better figure out what my actual duties will be.

> Support the Consulting efforts with shaping of the streamlining program, covering many deliverables and being a key initiative for the bank in 2014. Be involved in the vendor discussions to help establish requirements and the solution set.
>
> Help to define and establish the benefits’ management of programs and embed the changes within the Business Functions and Finance. Act on behalf of the Portfolio Manager at the program and project level to ensure that this is planned and executed with a view to leverage for all portfolios.

So is this kind of like a project management internship where the goal is to make the bank a leaner operation and support organizational change? Is the "Portfolio Manager" the project manager?

I didn't apply for this job but the recruiter contacted me saying that I would be a great fit and I'd love to explore the details further to see if this is a fit.

The job description is much longer than this but this is just subsection that I'd love to be able to better understand.

Comment: Job descriptions are, normally, guidelines. It would be better if you ask directly someone in the company: how would be a normal day of work for me there? Anyway, what you will end up doing is something you can only find out working.

Comment: as an intern, likely your responsibilites woudl be to attend meetings and take notes and produce dopcumentation of decisons other people make, you coudl also end up doing some data collection to support the decision making process.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific job description and not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: This is so vague only the company can answer it; maybe thorugh the recruiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Support the Consulting efforts with shaping of the streamlining
>   program, covering many deliverables and being a key initiative for the
>   bank in 2014. Be involved in the vendor discussions to help establish
>   requirements and the solution set.

The "establish requirements and the solution set" would be about figuring out what is needed and what options exist. The idea here could also be to see what are the advantages each vendor could bring in delivering a solution given requirements including timelines, budget and scope of work.

The key here would be capturing what are the "must have" features, what is "nice to have" and what is the long term plan for these new initiatives.

> Help to define and establish the benefits’ management of programs and
>   embed the changes within the Business Functions and Finance. Act on
>   behalf of the Portfolio Manager at the program and project level to
>   ensure that this is planned and executed with a view to leverage for
>   all portfolios.

Portfolio Manager here could mean a couple of different things as this is a bank:

IT meaning would be the collection of systems used by the bank for various processes. The work here would be about what is the benefit of implementing new systems and processes to improve the operation of the bank. While this is likely what is meant, there is also this other idea.

Finance meaning would be in reference to investments the bank makes with the deposits it has. There could be work here to generate better returns by having better approaches to things where program could be electronic or could be in-house courses offered possibly.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much for the in depth explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The person putting out the job requisition didn't have their thoughts organized all that well and this is reflected in the job spec.  They might have written it in a hurry.

Banks have various 'loan portfolios': Automobiles, Commercial Real Estate, Residential Real Estate, etc., etc. They might also have some 'asset portfolios' - either stocks they own, deposits, trusts, or commercial properties (huge banks often build skyscrapers, and lease floors out to tenants). Some of these are producing, others are probably breaking even, and when markets go south they lose money. The idea is to bring on new kinds of business that increases revenue, and dump the dogs.  First you have to know whether you should continue in a particular line of business or not.